# Laravel 5.3 - IP:Port in route gives 404

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to setup a laravel 5.3 route with

```
Route::get('/i/{ipport}', 'SomeController@index');
```

But when i go to http://localhost:8000/i/110.234.110.14:27031

it gives 404

The requested resource /i/110.234.110.14:27031 was not found on this server.

Comment: Php Artisan serve? Obvious questions first. Have you tried the where function? Routes::get(...)->where(['ipport' => "regex ip+port"]);... Was it the laravel 404?

Comment: Yes i am using php artisan serve. I tried Regex still does not work. 404 is different than laravel Not Found Exception

Comment: Maybe .* as regex? But you can access localhost:8000 ?

Comment: http://localhost:8000/i/110.234.110.14 works. But when i add a colon it gives 404. Yes i can access localhost.

Comment: try to use apache. maybe its an issue with php server. For example, you can't access 127.0.0.1:8000 if you use php artisan serve.

Comment: Did it work? Something new happend or still stuck?

Comment: Works with apache. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See our discussion in the comments of the question.

Problem is, that `php artisan serve` uses `php -S localhost:8000` (and some additional parameters)

That server is not able to parse the url correctly. (The : in this case)

The solution is simple: use apache (or other servers) and point the http directory to the public folder.